# How to list all items in a list in Terraform and what's the for loop equivalent here?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am kind of new to Terraform and could you help me with the lists in terraform.

This is my code

```
variable  "ip_bitbucket" {
  type = "list"
}
```

```
ip_bitbucket = ["34.199.54.113/32","34.232.25.90/32","34.232.119.183/32","34.236.25.177/32","35.171.175.212/32","52.54.90.98/32","52.202.195.162/32","52.203.14.55/32","52.204.96.37/32","34.218.156.209/32","34.218.168.212/32","52.41.219.63/32","35.155.178.254/32","35.160.177.10/32","34.216.18.129/32","3.216.235.48/32","34.231.96.243/32","44.199.3.254/32","174.129.205.191/32","44.199.127.226/32","44.199.45.64/32","3.221.151.112/32","52.205.184.192/32","52.72.137.240/32"]
```

and need to access the list as below

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule "server_rule" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
 # for each = var.ip_bitbucket
  cidr_blocks       = 
  security_group_id = data.aws_security_group.server_sg.id
}
```

How do i access the variable `ip_bitbucket` in cidr block?

I was trying with `count` and `element` but not getting clear idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for_each` argument requires either a map value (with any element type) or a set of strings. Your input variable is currently declared as being a list, and so it isn't directly compatible with `for_each`.

It seems like the order of the elements in `ip_bitbucket` has no significance and so I think the best answer would be to change the type constraint of that variable to be `set(string)`, which is a more accurate description of how you will use that value:

```
variable  "ip_bitbucket" {
  type = set(string)
}
```

However, you can specify more than one CIDR block in a single security group rule so you may not actually need `for_each` at all here:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "server_rule" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = var.ip_bitbucket
  security_group_id = data.aws_security_group.server_sg.id
}
```

The above will declare a single rule which applies to all of the given CIDR ranges.

If you *do* still want to use `for_each` then you can use `var.ip_bitbucket` as the `for_each` value once you've changed its type constraint as described above:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "server_rule" {
  for_each = var.ip_bitbucket

  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = [each.value]
  security_group_id = data.aws_security_group.server_sg.id
}
```

Noice that `each.value` needs to be in brackets here because `each.value` is just a single element from `var.ip_bitbucket`, and so it's a single string. `cidr_blocks` expects a set of strings.

If some other part of your module that you've not shown here *does* rely on the specific ordering of the elements in `var.ip_bitbucket` then you could leave it declared as a list and then convert it to a set inside the `for_each` argument. However, I would recommend this only if you really do need to preserve the order of these elements, because users or future maintainers of your module may assume that the ordering is important if you declare it as a list.

```
variable  "ip_bitbucket" {
  type = list(string)
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "server_rule" {
  for_each = toset(var.ip_bitbucket)

  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = [each.value]
  security_group_id = data.aws_security_group.server_sg.id
}
```

This is the same as the previous example except that the conversion from list to set happens explicitly with the `toset` function, rather than automatically as Terraform prepares the value of `var.ip_bitbucket`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `toset` built-in function [1] for that:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule "server_rule" {
  for_each          = toset(var.ip_bitbucket)
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = [each.value]
  security_group_id = data.aws_security_group.server_sg.id
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/toset

Comment: that's a perfect answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but am getting the below error
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
 156:   cidr_blocks       = each.value
Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": list of string required.

Comment: Was typing from my phone so forgot the square brackets.